# Card payments - order confirmed but no payment taken

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, payment-gateway

To Be Exact

The problem is intermitant and does not happen with the majority of card payments but too frequent to be ignored.

Customer goes through checkout and sees the order sucessful page and also receives a confirmation email.

On the back end the payment appears as Pending.......there is no money taken.

We rang our merchant services several times who have checked and say there was absolutely no visit to the payment pages and so the problem must lie in the magento configuration.

As said, majority of card payments are fine and those that say pending with no money taken have nothing in common. We are having to ring customers who have their payment marked as pending and on questioning nothing seems to be going wrong for them through the checkout process.

Anyone have any ideas at all for me to be able to sort this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check the Payment method that is currently active on store .

Answer (score 0):

Tahnk you Pankaj Pareek. I had checked the payment methods and indeed it seemed inocuous but the CC Saved was available. When the customer checked this and entered their details it appears as pending until we take the payment by MOTO.I didn't know this:( It is now an option remeoved. Something sooo small but so annoying to the unitiated.